# Submenu Behind Video

Tags: wordpress, menu

My submenu items are falling below the video on my homepage: http://www.customwebthemes.com/MarvinDiscovers/
Look at the submenu items under the menu item "Meet the Authors".
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this as the src of the iframe: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/_GPXSJ6qUIs?wmode=transparent`